# SXA Image not show

Tags: sxa

Just installed 9.1 and SXA, for image field is not show the image in both design and preview mode. In Chrome dev tool, after remove the ?h=350&w=480 at the end of the image link the image shows. Anyone know what caused this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Sitecore StackExchange.
Are you using the Wireframe theme? If so, please try switching themes in the Experience Editor to a different theme (if you have one), then click Save. This should load the image.

[image]

Comment: I also had to go to Presentation > Page Designs > Default (used by my page) and change the default theme there to not be Wireframe.

Comment: Thank you Mark and Jen, changing the theme resolved the issue!

Comment: Hi @FM102.4 Glad we could help. Please mark the answer as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as of SXA 1.8 the old Wireframe theme is deprecated. A new Wireframe theme is present (check  `/sitecore/media library/Themes/`) If you reset the **Mock Image** field of the theme then you will get your own images.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Content Editor, go to `sitecore/media library/themes` and choose the theme that you have selected.

After that see on your right side. You can see folder and content tab.

Click on content and then there will be yellow book icon.

Click and search for mock image and clear. Save and reload. That's all. You will get your image.